# Python share global variable only for functions inside of function

Tags: python, scope, global-variables, python-3.5

I have a function which will recursively execute another function inside and I want to share variable for all execution of that function.

Something like that:

```
def testglobal():
  x = 0
  def incx():
    global x
    x += 2
  incx()
  return x
testglobal() # should return 2
```

However, I'm getting error `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

There is hacky solution to make list and use first value of that list as `x`. But this is so ugly.

So how can I share `x` with `incx` function ? Or should I use completely different approach ?

Comment: In python 3 there is a new keyword, [nonlocal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement), that does exactly what you want. Keep in mind that this is a closure so you have access to `x` without alterations, but assigning (e.g. `x = 1`) inside `incx` will make `x` local to `incx` and therefore not refer to the same variable. `nonlocal` achieves this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `nonlocal` statement to access `x`, which is not global but local to `testglobal`.

```
def testglobal():
  x = 0
  def incx():
    nonlocal x
    x += 2
  incx()
  return x
assert 2 == testglobal()
```

The closest you can come to doing this in Python 2 is to replace `x` with a mutable value, similar to the argument hack you mentioned in your question.

```
def testglobal():
  x = [0]
  def incx():
    x[0] += 2
  incx()
  return x[0]
assert 2 == testglobal()
```

Here's an example using a function attribute instead of a list, an alternative that you might find more attractive.

```
def testglobal():
  def incx():
    incx.x += 2
  incx.x = 0
  incx()
  return inc.x
assert 2 == testglobal()
```

Comment: But this was introduced only in python 3, right ? But this concept looks so common for, how to do the same in python 2 ?

Comment: You can't, short of your mutable-argument hack. Closures only capture the value of a variable for reading; you can't modify the value nonlocally (which is why Python 3 added the `nonlocal` keyword).

Answer (score 3):

This will work unless you are still using Python 2.x:

```
def testglobal():
  x = 0
  def incx():
    nonlocal x
    x += 2
  incx()
  return x

testglobal() # should return 2
```

Possible a cleaner solution though would be to define a class to store your state between method calls.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) statement, so `incx` will use the `x` variable from `testglobal`:

```
def testglobal():
    x = 0
    def incx():
        nonlocal x
        x += 2
    incx()
    return x

testglobal()
```